# Findbugs report on a specific package or class file

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, findbugs

I have a multi module maven project that I am currently working.

1. I was wondering if there is any way to customize the *findbugs plugin* to generate xml reports on a *particular package* or *class files* rather than on all the projects. Is it possible to do this on project level or class level for that matter ?
2. I also want to exclude certain java files while generating the report on a project level is it possible as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the [findbugs-maven-plugin:usage](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/usage.html) page, section `Filter bugs to report`. It mentions about how to filter (include/exclude) some classes/methods/packages configuration.

Furthermore the information about how to configure the findbugs filter xml is also mentioned at [Chapter 8. Filter Files](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/filter.html)

I hope this may help.